# Manipulating validated data in Colander SchemaNode

Tags: python, pyramid, colander, cornice

I have a set of Colander SchemaNodes used with Pyramid/Cornice in an API.  For some querystring args, a range is passed (ie `time=X-Y` means a time range from X to Y where X and Y are integers representing epochs).  I currently validate this with a `RegEx()` validator to ensure an epoch or epoch range is passed in:

```
class TimeOrRange(SchemaNode):
    schema_type = String
    location = "querystring"
    description = 'Time (or range) in epochs: ssssssssss(-ssssssssss)'
    validator = Regex("^[0-9]{10}\-{0,1}[0-9]{0,10}$")
```

I then use this in a MappingSchema which is then tied to my Cornice view with `@view(schema=TimedThingGet)`:

```
class TimedThingGet(MappingSchema):
    time = TimeOrRange(missing=drop)
```

What I would like to do is update the return value in my `TimeOrRange` SchemaNode code so `time` in `TimedThingGet` is a tuple of time ranges.  In other words, if `time=X-Y` is passed in to a `TimedThingGet` instance, then `time=(x, y)` is returned in the validated data.  Similarly, if only `X` is passed in, then I want `Y` to be set to the epoch of `now()`.

It looks like `set_value()` is the way to go, and here's where the problem get's some extra credit:

1. Does `set_value` get called before or after validation?
2. Does `set_value` have access to the validator such that a `RegEx` validator which creates regex groups could then be used to set my tuple: `time=(validated.match.group[1], validated.match.group[2])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should actually look at:

Preparer callable that you can pass to SchemaNode:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/interfaces.html?highlight=preparer#colander.interfaces.Preparer

It will allow you to manipulate the data before it is passed to validators

And optionally at:

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/binding.html#what-is-schema-binding

Which allows you set additional properies after schema is instantiated.

Comment: Great advice.  A missing piece of using a preparer is that one must use the Function() validator with a custom validator function to parse the prepared value.  I say this only because my original question wanted to make use of groups from a RegEx validator, which is not directly possible.  The workaround is to use a regex in a preparer and save groups to, say, a list.  A custom validator function can then take the list and validate.